# How to parameterise a parabola with a particle running on it at a given speed, say 10 m/s.

Tags: conic-sections, constraints

If I use t=x, it will dictate a uniform velocity in the x-direction, and eventually violate the constraint.  Could use some hints.
[edit: ... at a given speed, not velocity, my apologies].

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you consider its velocity.
As you give a scalar quantity and no direction, I would assume the constraint is about the length of the velocity vector.

$$
10 = \lVert v \rVert = \sqrt{ v\cdot v }
$$

A parametrization of the parabola is
$$
u = (f(t), f(t)^2)^T
$$
it leads to
$$
v = \dot{u} = (\dot{f}(t), 2\,f(t)\, \dot{f}(t))^T
$$
and 
\begin{align}
10 &= \sqrt{(\dot{f}(t))^2+ 4 \,f(t)^2 \, (\dot{f}(t))^2} \\
   &= \left\lvert \dot{f}(t) \right\rvert \sqrt{1 + 4 \, f(t)^2}
\end{align}
For positive $\dot{f}$ this means
$$
10 \, dt = \sqrt{1 + 4 \, f(t)^2} \, df
$$
which according to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20sqrt(1%20%2B%204%20f%5E2)%20df) leads to
$$
t = \frac{1}{20} f(t) \sqrt{4 f(t)^2+1}+\frac{1}{40} \sinh^{-1}(2 f(t)) + C
$$
And I fear this leaves only a numerical calculation of $f = t^{-1}$, like in this [WA result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%2010%20%3D%20sqrt%28f%27%5E2%20%2B%20%282*f*f%27%29%5E2%29%20for%20f).

Comment: You're right, that's exactly what was intended.  Question was edited accordingly.

Comment: Don't you mean $u=(f(t),f(t)^2)$?

Comment: I guess that will change the formulas that follow as well

Comment: Yes. Good you stopped me.

Comment: And now you also need $(1+4f(t)^2)\dot{f}(t)^2$ under the radical, right?

Comment: Ok, all good now. Finally, +1 for your answer. ;) But you could still be more consistent in the notation -- I would use either $\dot{f}$ and $f$, or $\dot{f}(t)$ and $f(t)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : velocity of the particle = $$\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}$$ and you should know the expression of $y$ because $y(t)=f(x(t))$ with $f$ your parabola equation

Comment: Using y=5+0.3x^2, I get y'=0.6xx', or 10^2=x'^2+y'^2.

Comment: not sure how to relate x(t) with y(t) incorporating the constraint.  Btw, are the equations written in latex or ps?

Comment: using your parabola : $$100 = x'^2+0.36x^2x'^2$$ and you have to solve this differential equation

Comment: ok, will give it a try.  Thank you.